# Assumptions to be checked under Tobit model

Tags: assumptions, tobit-regression

Some researchers suggest that OLS assumptions must also be satisfied for other estimations (like Tobit, probit/logit, Heckman two-stage model). From the discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136100/ols-assumptions/) I understand that it makes no sense to check OLS assumptions for other than OLS estimations. Currently I have employed a Tobit model.

**Question:** What are the relevant assumptions to be checked for the Tobit model?

Comment: This is covered in almost all texts on microeconmetrics. The canonical source for this sort of thing is [Maddala's book](http://amzn.com/0521338255). Modern treatments can be found in [Wooldridge's graduate text (Chapter 17)](http://amzn.com/0262232588), or in [Cameron and Trivedi's book (ch. 16)](http://amzn.com/0521848059). You should be able to get a hold of worked examples in [Cameron & Trivedi's accompanying Stata book](http://amzn.com/1597180734).

Answer (score 2):

The issues mentioned in the other discussion you've linked (multicollinearity, heteroskedasticity, and endogeneity) equally apply to tobit models, and have even more severe consequences if ignored. Multicollinearity leads to pretty much the same issues in tobit as it does in linear regression, ranging from instable estimates (near-perfect multicollinearity) to unidentifiable estimates (perfect multicollinearity).

Ignoring either heteroskedasticity or endogeneity (or both) results in a mispecified likelihood function and therefore *inconsistent* estimates. See section 6.12 in [Maddala's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521338255) (mentioned by tchakravarty above) for how to deal with heteroskedasticity. Dealing with endogeneity is even more complicated: depending on its precise nature: stochastic regressors will need a modified likelihood function as described in [Stapleton & Young](https://doi.org/10.2307/1913474). More complicated types of endogeneity will require simultaneous-equation models.